# Text block comparison python

Tags: python, text, compare

I have a python project in mind but i'm not too sure where to start.

I want to do some text comparison between two blocks of text, I want a user to be able to input two blocks of text and the program to identify the parts that are different/not the same.

I've seen this functionality in Git - when you make a change in a repo, it shows you the changes before you commit - this makes me think that I should be able to make something with similar functionality.

Any kinda' insight would be greatly appreciated!!

EDIT:
While searching I came across this Git repo online, it's all i'm looking for! A simple GUI interface where a user can load two different files and see the similarities or differences between them!

For others looking for something similar: https://github.com/yebrahim/pydiff

Comment: Have a look at git source code? :-)

Comment: @JanStránský I would but, I think I would be a little out of my depth - I'm still a novice programmer

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, you can take user input and store it in two strings say `str1` and `str2` then you can make use of `split( )` method or rather `word_tokenize( )`(Natural Language Processing) to get all the words in the String

If you want you can also remove **stopwords** [Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_text_processing/python_remove_stopwords.htm) for better comparison

Now you can run a loop comparing each word and for clear perception, you can underline the words or a particular part of a word that doesn't match